# If X has beta distribution, how do you show that 1 - X also has beta distribution with parameters switched?

Tags: probability, statistics

This is problem presented to me:

Suppose that $X$ has the beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Show that $1 - X$ has the beta distribution with parameters $\beta$ and $\alpha$.

Do you simply plug in $(1 - x)$ as $x$ into the beta distribution p.d.f.? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're very polite and you posed your question consecutively in grammatically correct sentences. This is rare on this website, but don't you think it is enough to make a mathematician. Use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) from now on.

Answer (score 2):

$$f_{1-X}(x)=f_X(1-x){}{}{}{}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the CDF technique for $Y=1-X$.

$$P(Y<y)=P(1-X<y)=P(X>1-y)= \int_{1-y}^1 \frac{\Gamma(\alpha +\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\times \Gamma(\beta)} x^{a-1} (1-x)^{\beta -1} dx $$

Differentiate wrt $y$ using Leibniz's formula.

Comment: How do you finish the problem using Leibniz's formula? Thanks.

Comment: "Differentiate wrt y using Leibniz's formula." Sorry but I do not want to do that. Use instead the change of variable $z=1-x$.

Comment: @Did As long as the OP recognises that the Jacboain disappears only in special cases and normally it cannot be overlooked.

Comment: ?? How is your comment related to my comment about your answer?

Comment: @Did The absolute value of the Jacobian is 1 here. So if the OP has not heard of the technique before he might be tempted to substitute directly from now on. That is my point.

Comment: To attempt to compute PDFs of transforms of random variables avoiding all kind of change of variable strikes me as a futile (even destructive) approach. If this is the motive of your answer being phrased the way it is, then sorry, but I am not convinced.

Comment: @Did It's useful to know the CDF technique as well, just in case  the change of variables technique is not applicable. By the way would you mind giving your opinion on one of the questions I asked? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610392/an-application-of-ldct

Comment: You are shifting arguments... but no big deal. About the other question: how does the posted answer fail to satisfy you?

Comment: @Did It does not fail at all. But since I do not think Daniel has training in probability, is there anything you would like to add? Thank you.

Comment: This is insulting to another user (and, in the specific case, quite off-the-mark). (To be frank, I was afraid you would come to this kind of misplaced statement. Even if you saw users on MSE behave like that, I strongly object to it and do not want to be a part of it.)

Comment: @Did I am sorry. I did not want to offend anyone. I am nothing but grateful for the help I have received. I will drop it now.

Comment: "Drop it now"? Just READ the answer and THINK about it! This is maths, not voodoo...

Comment: @Did Not what I meant. I meant I will not discuss this anymore because you are right and I am embarassed. That is all.